# Inserting File Permission and sharing with type "group" does not send notification email in Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

When I create a file and insert a permission while setting the value to a group email address and type to "**group**", no notification email is sent but when I try just a single user and type "user", I get notification email. Also When I check the file in Drive, I see the file marked as shared even though it does not appear in the users (part of the group) Drive account. What can I be doing wrong?

**Note:** The file with the permission resides in a folder, could that be a problem? I should think not...

Comment: Is this related to the Google Drive API or the Google Drive web UI?

Comment: Yes Alain, It is related to the Google Drive API. When I share a normal text file, it successfully sends the notification email but when I upload a file (doc or pdf), it does not send the notification emails even though when I switch to the Drive UI, I see the file marked as shared.

Comment: I juste tried with the [APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.permissions.insert) and it worked perfectly: e-mails were sent wether I shared with a user or a group. Can you make sure you set the `?sendNotificationEmails=` query parameter to `true`?

Comment: Yes Alain I did set the sendNotificationEmails to true. I am using the PHP SDK (Latest from SVN) and when I create a new file, I immediately get the file id and create a permission for the created file while setting the following: 

`$permission = new Google_Permission();
$permission->setValue('group@binghamuni.edu.ng');
$permission->setType('group');
$permission->setRole('reader');

$drive->permissions->insert($file_id, $permission, array('sendNotificationEmails' => TRUE));`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way around this funny problem I was encountering. So I happen to find out that When I **URL-encoded** the File title and shared it, it worked for both users and groups. So I figured Google Drive does not like funny characters in the File title when sharing. I stand to be corrected though, but that seemed to solve my problem temporarily pending when someone will come out with a valid explanation.

Comment: Could you share a file title for which it fails so we can try and reproduce? Thanks!

Comment: Ok Alain, I tried sending a name like this "Google+ Demo Assessment" and it faile but when I take out the + from Google+, it sends the notification emails.